# Braces removing from a given path in tcl

Tags: tcl, text-classification

Suppose I have a path like `{\$ALLO/afg}`.
I want to remove the starting and ending braces by using `regsub` or `regexp`.

Comment: I think you may be using string commands on a list value (and vice versa) -- can you show some code that shows how the variable is created?

Comment: Also, show your attempt of using `regsub` (`regexp` won't be much of a help).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can remove the braces with:

```
# Assuming that the value is in a variable called “value” and you want to modify it
regsub {^\{(.*)\}$} $value {\1} value
```

But I've got a suspicion that something is more deeply wrong with your code, such as using `lrange` to pick a single element instead of `lindex`.